# How to display image which was uploaded by Multer when query data with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, reactjs, image, upload, multer

As title says, I want to display avatar but it has  `uploads\\img.jpg` path, how to display it in frontend part of a application for example when you get user info from the database ?

Here is the user data:

```
{ 
       username: 'm',
       name: 'm',
       email: 'mmerko@gmail.com',
       id: '5b64247eb03a573b2818f3c4',
       avatar: 'uploads\\img-1533289594220.jpg'
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this
Go to your app.js file and do this
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));

The reason is because by default the folder is not publicly accessible and you don't have a route that handles getting files from that url

Answer (score 4):

So, first of all, if you want to operate with images (or other static files) with you're Node.js server you need to [configure static paths](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Then, let's says you configured it with path `/uploads` and (for example) you're Node.js server running on `localhost:3000` then you can access to any file in this directory by given path

```
http://localhost:3000/uploads/example.jpg
```

With this path you can display image on front end using [img tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)

```
<img src="http://localhost:3000/uploads/example.jpg"/>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have static path, I should manually set the src beginning like `localhost:3000/${avatar}` ?

Comment: Yes, but if you really receive avatar path like this `uploads\\avatar.jpg` I would suggest to format it to `/uploads/avatar.jpg` and then you'll have `http://localhost:3000${avatarPath}`. Of course it would be better if you'll move `localhost:3000` to some kind of environment variable to change it depending on you'r preferences, but it's topic for another thread.

Comment: I'm trying to show a image, it doesn't work, it doesn't work even if I put like `http://localhost:5000/uploads/IMG_20180802_072445.jpg-1533289594220.jpg`

Comment: Is image has the right name? Because `IMG_20180802_072445.jpg-1533289594220.jpg` seems to me not correct (2 times of `.jpg`)

Comment: Yes, I know that, I need to change multer config, it works when I run in browser, but in app it shows nothing..

Comment: Did you solve your problem because I am having the same problem in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61526799/nodejs-multer-get-id-but-not-displaying